# How to get user name instead of SID during WMI logcollection

Tags: windows, wmi, wmi-query, group-policy, wql

I'm looking for a possible solution to convert a **Windows user SID** to a **username**.

I am running WQL queries against some local namespace and would like to know if there are any possibilities to get a username instead SID like an **event viewer**. I am using WBEMTest for testing.

Screenshot for reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM Win32_AccountSID` should get you a list you can match the SID to the name.

Comment: Do we able to see the username in the Message field of win32_ntlogevent class itself like the above-attached event viewer screenshot ?

Comment: I assume you need some extra processing but this is Stackoverflow so I assume that is not an issue.